# Kafka topic creation command

Tags: apache-kafka

I am referring to a book on Kafka. To create a Kafka topic, it states:

> Using the command line utility for creating topics on the Kafka server, let’s create a topic named replicated-kafkatopic with two partitions and two replicas:
>
> `kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic replicated-kafkatopic`

While text states to create 2 partitions and 2 replicas, arguments passed are: 3 for replication-factor and 1 for partitions.

Are arguments correct in context of what text states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it must be a typo. If you want to create a topic with two partitions and two replicas, the command should be as follows:

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic replicated-kafkatopic
```

The command that you have provided, creates a topic `replicated-kafkatopic` with 1 partition (`--partitions 1`) and 3 replicas (`--replication-factor 3`).